# Why do some things not run on it?

Tags: java, android

Why does some Java code not run/work when packaged as an APK and deployed to an Android device? Things like Google Guice, Apache Camel and many other projects. Isn't it all just plain ole' Java?

Comment: Java the language, yes, "Java" the collection of classes - yes there is much overlap, but there are also critical differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Plain ole' Java" or "100% pure Java" don't really exist outside of the language specification. You're dealing with a totally different virtual machine model and different class libraries.  [The Dalvik VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) wasn't implemented with the intention of being compatible with desktop JVM implementations (Sun/Oracle, OpenJDK, etc). It doesn't even directly run Java bytecode; it is compiled into a Dalvik-specific instruction set and otherwise mangled in an attempt to create smaller executable packages and to run well on mobile platforms that are often resource-constrained.

Comment: Thanks @Donald (+1) - then what's the "rule of thumb" regarding what libraries/packages won't run on Android?!? How do I know if my project dependencies are "Android safe"?

Comment: You should consult the [Android SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) to see if a specific class library is available on the platform. If you are referring to third-party dependencies, then it isn't as simple as tossing a jar file into your apk and deploying it; you'll need the Java source code for it and will have to rebuild it using the SDK for it to run properly on Dalvik. This may or may not involve some tweaking to get it to build.

Answer (score 2):

No. There are a lot of custom libraries and frameworks to help manage the life cycle of your applications.

I'm not sure exactly what Camel and Guice is. However, (some one please correct me if I'm wrong) is the Android Framework. The Operating System has ways of scheduling things to be ran. That's your Application's entire life cycle. And if you just start running pure java code where is the hook for the OS? It needs something to control. I suppose in theory your code can just run happily in its DM, but I suspect it won't play nicely with anything.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer @Frank (+1) but this fails to explain to me why Camel (which is 100% pure Java) or Guice won't run on Android.

Comment: Java compiles to bytecode, regardless of what framework (Guice, Camel or otherwise) it comes from. Posters question is legitimate: why doesn't Android run some Java packages? I suspect (as has been pointed out) there are some discrepancies between some fundamental JRE types and how Dalvik implements them, and that certain frameworks (like Guice which is reflection-heavy) extensively use these types for which Dalvik has no equivalent. But this is just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Let me expand on Frank's answer.  If you took the engine out of a diesel and put it in a regular car; would it run?  They are both engines.

Short answer:  Android wants to be secure.  It doesn't like executing code just willy nilly by the seat of it's pants.  For it to run Java code, it needs a wrapper.  That wrapper is the APK and to some degree the android manifest.  Once Android sees these things, it knows WHAT its running as well as HOW to run it.  Lets go back to my analogy of a diesel engine in a standard car.  It would be possible to make that work, but you would have to do some modification so that the car (Android) knows how to handle the engine (the diesel engine).

Android runs Linux at it's heart; under your mode of thinking you should be able to run linux native applications right?  You can see where I'm going with this.

Even shorter answer:  in many ways Android isn't java at all.  It's its own unique language, with caveats and quirks but the same syntax.

Comment: Thanks @user - please see my comment to Donald's answer - I have the same question for you! Thanks again (+1)!

Comment: Essentially all Java Packages and Libraries should run on Android (as long as they aren't looking for something that's hardware related)  However, this doesn't mean you can simply package your application as an APK and go.  You will need to take the time to set up Activities instead of UI built with swing for instance.  Basically, trying to run an app written in java without porting it to android is like sticking a playstation game in an xbox just because they are both written in C++

Comment: Then why don't Camel or Guice run?

Comment: Because they are not Android compliant.  You can't cook a steak in the freezer.  The stove and the freezer both can have food put in them, but they handle that food differently.  The square block does not fit in the round hole.

Comment: Ugggghh - i get your anologies! Where is the documentation that says "this is Android compliant" or "this is not Android compliant".

Comment: There isn't a document that explicitly states that (that I know of).  I don't think they where planning on people trying to run any applications that weren't coded specifically to run on their OS.  If you think you can take a Java app and just run it it will never happen no matter what is in the package.  You have to have a manifest, activities, etc.  If it's not specifically an Android application your application will not work no matter how you try.  The only applications that are android compliant are written to run on android.  I'm not sure how else I can put this...

Comment: OK - I think I need to be more specific; I will ask a different question that gets to the root of my misunderstanding.